# wpf : Bind to a control in another xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a main.xaml file. In the main.xaml file, It refer to a listbox in another xaml file. It is call using view:LayoutViewList

In the main.xaml file, There is a button. The button will be enable only when listbox is selected. Look like ElementName=view.LayoutViewList.LayoutListBox is not working. Thank you very much

```
Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=view:LayoutViewList.LayoutListBox, Path=SelectedItems.Count}"
```

Binding error  :

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=view:LayoutViewList.LayoutListBox'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItems.Count; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=view:LayoutViewList.LayoutListBox'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedIndex; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

Comment: Why you don't use the same list for the two xaml?? I am not sure that you can ref to another xaml file...

Comment: Because the listbox control has a lot of code, so it has been moved to another xaml file. How can I access to the listbox from the main.xaml ?

Comment: Ok. So you need to create a UserControl that will get data. And then you can re-use your customer usercontrol wherever you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`RelativeSource Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) if the view with the `Binding` is a child of your `MainView` file. Try this:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:MainView}}" />
```

This `Binding` refers to the `Count` property of the object exposed by the `SelectedItems` property *in the object that is set as the `DataContext`* of the `UserControl` or `Window` named `MainView`.

Comment: Many Thanks. Please would elaborate this : Binding DataContext.SelectedItems.Count

Comment: You said "UserControl or Window named MainView", that hardly can be a truth, in fact it finds for a RelativeSource of TYPE MainView.