# wpf binding to element from another xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, view, binding

I am trying to bind some data from the `MainWindow` to a second file (Type: `UserControl`). The second xaml-file should contain the data from a `TabItem`.
I found this answer: [wpf : Bind to a control in another xaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049845/wpf-bind-to-a-control-in-another-xaml-file)
but somehow I am not getting it, maybe because I am new to wpf and xaml.

I made a short example, to show my problem:

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingBetweenFiles.MainWindow"
...
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingBetweenFiles"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <TabControl Height="200">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
            <local:Tab1 />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <TextBlock Name="txtblock1">This text should be shown in the tab.</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Tab1 (Content for TabItem):

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingBetweenFiles.Tab1"
         ...
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingBetweenFiles"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         DataContext="local:MainWindow"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding DataContext.txtblock1.Text, RelativeSource={
                     RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
</Grid>
```

I wonder if the declaration of the `DataContext` is wrong or if the binding is the problem?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Isn't it better to use MVVM pattern? Having xaml file only as representation, and all actual data stored in separate ViewModel class. Then, both your MainWindow and UserControl can bind to same property of ViewModel, using it as DataContext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all you would want is to be able to bind a `string` to the `Tab1` "text", create a `DependencyProperty` in the code-behind for the `UserControl`:

```
public string TabText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TabTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TabTextProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TabTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TabText", typeof(string), typeof(Tab1), new PropertyMetadata("Default"));
```

Then in the `Tab1` XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingBetweenFiles.Tab1"
     ...
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingBetweenFiles"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     DataContext="local:MainWindow"
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
     x:Name="tab1Control">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=tab1Control, Path=TabText"/>
</Grid>
```

Then in your Window XAML:

```
<local:Tab1 TabText="The text you want to place."/>
```

Or you can also bind to TabText, eg:

```
<local:Tab1 TabText="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```